# "dimnames_zoo" not resolved from current namespace (xts)

Tags: r, namespaces, xts, zoo

I have written an R script which downloads stock prices from the internet and regularly updates my database. The script uses the xts package among other things.
I run it automatically every night (from a mac). It worked for about 6 months. Recently it stopped working and reports the following error at any xts call:

"dimnames_zoo" not resolved from current namespace (xts)

The strange thing is that if I open R manually and run the script from there, it works perfectly with no error. I installed the last version of R (3.3.2) and updated all packages, hoping that this could fix the error. However, the automatic script still does not work.

When the script runs automatically (and generates the error), this is what SessionInfo() reports:

```
SessionInfo:R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.2

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] methods   stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  base     

other attached packages:
[1] quantmod_0.4-7                TTR_0.23-1                   
[3] PerformanceAnalytics_1.4.3541 xts_0.9-7                    
[5] zoo_1.7-14                    RCurl_1.95-4.8               
[7] bitops_1.0-6                  mailR_0.4.1                  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] lattice_0.20-34   R.methodsS3_1.7.1 grid_3.3.2        magrittr_1.5     
[5] stringi_1.1.2     R.oo_1.21.0       R.utils_2.5.0     tools_3.3.2      
[9] stringr_1.1.0     inline_0.3.14     rJava_0.9-8
```

When instead I run the script directly by opening R this is what I get from SessionInfo():

```
SessionInfo:R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.2

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] quantmod_0.4-7                TTR_0.23-1                              PerformanceAnalytics_1.4.3541 xts_0.9-7                    
[5] zoo_1.7-14                    RCurl_1.95-4.8                bitops_1.0-6                      mailR_0.4.1                  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] lattice_0.20-34   R.methodsS3_1.7.1 grid_3.3.2        magrittr_1.5          stringi_1.1.2     R.oo_1.21.0       R.utils_2.5.0    
[8] tools_3.3.2       stringr_1.1.0     inline_0.3.14     rJava_0.9-8
```

I do not know what else to try. Any help would be welcome.
John

Comment: Output of `traceback()` could shed more light on the underlying issue.

Comment: I am not sure how I should use this function in the script (sorry I am not that expert). I put it immediately after the first call to xts. This is what I got  in the error report:

Comment: Error in .Call("dimnames_zoo", x) : 
  "dimnames_zoo" not resolved from current namespace (xts)
Calls: reportsIB -> colnames -> dimnames -> dimnames.xts -> .Call
Esecuzione interrotta

Comment: The function call just tries to convert a csv to xts:   nav0 <- as.xts(read.zoo(read.csv(paste0(inputDir, "NAV.csv"))))

Comment: I suspect the file "NAV.csv" is not being created in script mode, could you confirm this.

Comment: NAV.csv is a file on my mac. The scripts reads it from the hard drive, convert it to xts and then proceeds to update it

Comment: Could you try this: `nav_DF <- read.csv(paste0(inputDir, "NAV.csv"));nav0 = xts(nav_DF[,-1],order.by=as.Date(nav_DF[,1],format="%Y-%m-%d"));`  and replace `format=` with the date format of NAV.csv, current format resembles date such as `2017-02-06`

Comment: I just tried this but it did not work. Same error...

Comment: What is the output of `dput(head(nav_DF[,1]))`

Comment: I get a vector of dates: 2015-04-29 2015-04-30 2015-05-01 2015-05-04 2015-05-05 2015-05-06

Comment: Please edit the post with output of `dateInput = dput(head(nav_DF[,1]))`  with complete output beginning `structure...`

Comment: I hade to change  dateInput to dput(head(nav_DF[,1,drop=F])), otherwise I would not any structure out of it. This is what I get now: structure(list(Date = c("2015-04-29", "2015-04-30", "2015-05-01", 
"2015-05-04", "2015-05-05", "2015-05-06")), .Names = "Date", row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134971/discussion-between-john-and-osssan).

Answer (score 0):

Could you try replicating this result:

```
 library("xts")

 mtcars_new = mtcars
 mtcars_new$mpg = head(seq(Sys.Date()-nrow(mtcars_new),Sys.Date(),by=1),nrow(mtcars_new))
 mtcars_xts = xts(mtcars_new[,-1],order.by=as.Date(mtcars_new[,1],format="%Y-%m-%d"))

 head(mtcars_xts)

 head(mtcars_xts)
 #           cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
 #2017-01-05   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
 #2017-01-06   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
 #2017-01-07   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
 #2017-01-08   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
 #2017-01-09   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
 #2017-01-10   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Comment: I did create the xts object and reported it correctly:

Comment: is.xts TRUE
           cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
2017-01-05   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2017-01-06   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
2017-01-07   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
2017-01-08   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
2017-01-09   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
2017-01-10   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1

Comment: I am sorry I printed the xts object in a messy way but I do not know how to print it like you did :(

Comment: What are the column names in NAV.csv and especially what is the first column a) is it Date b) is it row indices (1,2,3..)

Comment: Hi Osssan the situation is very confusing for me. Right now I just opened R from RStudio (as I do normally) and the xts package gives me an error even with R opened (which is strange as it normally never does). For instance I tried the marcars_xts example and now I get Error in .Call("dimnames_zoo", x) : 
  "dimnames_zoo" not resolved from current namespace (xts)

Comment: str(mtcars_new$mpg) gives me Date[1:32], format: "2017-01-05" "2017-01-06" "2017-01-07" "2017-01-08" "2017-01-09" "2017-01-10" "2017-01-11" "2017-01-12" ... so it is a date object

Comment: a very erratic behaviour .

Comment: xts is loaded correctly. but whatever xts object I try to create I get the same error

Comment: To isolate package issue (xts specific) vs. systemwide (R issue), would suggest to create a backup of `/path-to-R/library/xts/` and remove/cut it from this path. Open a new R session, install `xts` version `install.packages("xts",dep=TRUE)` and retry your code.

Comment: I did that. Right now it is working. The strange thing is that I had re-installed R and updated all packages only 3 days ago with the hope that it would fix the problem. But it did not. Maybe I should have deleted xts first as you suggested here. Anyway I hope it keeps working. I will find out in the next few days. Thank you a lot for your help